# (Chart.js) Is there a way to compare one chart with another so as not to have this inconsistent effect of small values being as big as big values?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, chart.js

I have several charts on a production tracking page, I'd like to avoid this effect that makes tracking inconsistent at first glance. Is there any option in chart.js for that ? If not, what is the best way to resolve this problem ?

[image]

I tried the option "bar percentage : 0.2", but the problem is it resolves only the width, not the height, and it causes another problem where there are several datas (it's ugly) :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will need to know the max value of your first chart. If you know this you can set the the `suggestedMax` value in the `ticks` options for the yAxes to that value.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [2],
      borderWidth: 1,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMax: 25
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```